# Merge Beautifulsoup and Mechanize to fill a form and retrieve results from the same URL

Tags: python, forms, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to fill the form on https://www.cancer.duke.edu/Nomogram/firstlinechemotherapy.html with multiple values and get results. Please note that the URL does not change on submit. (Validate button)

I have tried to fill the form with Mechanize and extract the result with Beautifulsoup. But I am not able to get my head around receiving a response as the URL never changes.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import mechanize

#Fill form with mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://www.cancer.duke.edu/Nomogram/firstlinechemotherapy.html")
response = br.response()
mech=response.read()
br.select_form(id='myform')
br.form['alb']='7'
br.form['hemo']='17'
br.form['alkph']='5000'
br.form['psa']='5000'
br.submit()

#Extract Output
url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.cancer.duke.edu/Nomogram/firstlinechemotherapy.html")
content = url.read()
soup= bsoup(content,"html.parser")
riskValue=soup.find('div',{'id':'resultPanelRisk3'})
tableValue=riskValue.find('table')
trValue=tableValue.find_all('tr')[1]
LowValue=trValue.find('td',{'id':'Risk3Low'}).string
IntermediateValue=trValue.find('td',{'id':'Risk3Intermediate'}).string
HighValue=trValue.find('td',{'id':'Risk3High'}).string
```

With the above code the value for LowValue is '*', whereas the expected LowValue for above mentioned form values is 'Yes'.

Comment: look like you're not parsing the output of your br object, mech? so whatever your output of br is, in your next block of code you're not using it. as far as i know mechanize and urllib dont talk to each automatically.  also check out requests and selenium, many have great experience automating the browser or sending custom headers

Comment: Is there a way to get mechanize and beautifulsoup talk to each other?

Comment: Why not use RoboBrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier and more efficient doing this using the [requests library](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/), so your code should look something like this:

```
import requests

alb='7'
hemo='17'
alkph='5000'
psa='5000'

url = f"https://www.cancer.duke.edu/Nomogram/EquationServer?pred=1&risk=1&lnm=0&bm=0&visc=0&pain=0&ldh=0&psanew=0&alb={alb}&hemo={hemo}&alkph={alkph}&psa={psa}&equationName=90401&patientid=&comment=&_=1556956911136"
req = requests.get(url).text

results = req[req.index("Row6=")+5:].strip().split(",")
results_transform = ['Yes' if x == '1' else 'No' for x in results]

LowValue = results_transform[2] 
IntermediateValue= results_transform[3] 
HighValue= results_transform[4]
```

---

**PS:**

the `results` variable outputs something like this:

```
['NA', 'NA', '1', 'NA', 'NA']
```

where the last three elements are  `Risk3Low`, `Risk3Intermediate` and `Risk3High` respectively. Furtheremore `"NA" = "No"` and `"1" = "Yes"`.

Which is why I'm using `results_transform` in order to transform

```
['NA', 'NA', '1', 'NA', 'NA']
```

into:

```
['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No']
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. This works too. Could you please let me know how and where did you get the url from?

Comment: @Prithvi Great! I got the url by intercepting the traffic of the website using [burp suite](https://portswigger.net/burp). There are many tutorials available out there on how to do it it's quite straight forward and doesn't require any coding. If you have any other problems feel free to ask!